# self join in pyspark dataframe with timestamp

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark dataframe as follows

```
+--+--------+-----------+
|id| account|       time|     
+--+--------+-----------+
| 4|      aa| 01/01/2017|    
| 2|      bb| 03/01/2017|    
| 6|      cc| 04/01/2017|    
| 1|      bb| 05/01/2017|      
| 5|      bb| 09/01/2017|    
| 3|      aa| 02/01/2017|
+--+--------+-----------+
```

and I want get the data as follows

```
+---+---+-------+
|id1|id2|account|
+---+---+-------+
|  4|  3|     aa|
|  2|  5|     bb|
|  1|  5|     bb|
|  2|  1|     bb|
+---+---+-------+
```

so I need find any possible pair within an account, and `id1` would be the id with the earlier time and `id2` would be the id with later time.
I'm very new to pyspark, I think self join maybe a good start.
Anyone can help me with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can achieve this using a self join:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.alias('l').join(df.alias('r'), on='account')\
    .where('r.time > l.time')\
    .select(f.col('l.id').alias('id1'), f.col('r.id').alias('id2'), 'l.account')\
    .show()
#+---+---+-------+
#|id1|id2|account|
#+---+---+-------+
#|  1|  5|     bb|
#|  2|  1|     bb|
#|  2|  5|     bb|
#|  4|  3|     aa|
#+---+---+-------+
```

- Join the DataFrame (`df`) to itself on the `account`. (We alias the left and right DataFrames as `'l'` and `'r'` respectively.)
- Next filter using `where` to keep only the rows where `r.time > l.time`.
- Everything left will be pairs of `id`s for the same `account` where `l.id` occurs before `r.id`.