# How to can pair all the value in field using partitionby on three fields

Tags: python, pyspark

I have been thinking of how to transform this DataFrame

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('312','Pbge', '06/20/2011', '95951', 359.93),
        ('312','Pbge', '06/20/2011', '95957',60.10),
        ('591','iTW', '11/13/2011', '92341',75.87),
        ('591','iTW', '11/13/2011', 'v2020',23.77),                                     
        ('591','iTW', '11/13/2011', 'v2211',66.02),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '71020',9.03),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '94060',44.60),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '94640',15.53),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '99213',36.63)
    ],
    schema=('bene_id','rend', 'date', 'code','amt')
)
```

into this

```
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('312','Pbge', '06/20/2011', '95951', 359.93,'95951', '95957'),
        ('312','Pbge', '06/20/2011', '95957',60.10, '95957','95951'),
        ('591','iTW', '11/13/2011', '92341',75.87,'92341','v2020'),
        ('591','iTW', '11/13/2011', '92341',75.87,'92341','v2211'),
        ('591','iTW', '11/13/2011', 'v2020',23.77,'v2020','92341'),
        ('591','iTW', '11/13/2011', 'v2020',23.77,'v2020','v2211'),
        ('591','iTW', '11/13/2011', 'v2211',66.027,'v2211','92341'),
        ('591','iTW', '11/13/2011', 'v2211',66.02,'v2211','v2020'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '71020',9.03,'71020','94060'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '71020',9.03,'71020','94640'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '71020',9.03,'71020','99213'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '94060',44.6,'94060','71020'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '94060',44.6,'94060','94640'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '94060',44.6,'94060','99213'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '94640',15.53,'94640','71020'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '94640',15.53,'94640','94060'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '94640',15.53,'94640','99213'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '99213',36.63,'99213','71020'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '99213',36.63,'99213','94060'),
        ('195','Y1b', '08/25/2011', '99213',36.63,'99213','94640')
    ],
    schema=('bene_id','rend', 'date', 'code','amt','col1', 'col2')
)
```

Doing a partionby on `bene_id, rend and data`, where it is true, I want pair all the items in code in `col1` and `col2`. `amt` should be `col1` as it appears in df1. The result is df2. This would be applied on a very large data. The dataframes are shown in the images below 
[image]
[image]
I need help.

Comment: You're probably looking for a simple join but I can not follow what you're asking. Please explain the logic in more detail, and provide the smallest possible [mcve] (i.e. can't you express the same question with a dataframe fewer rows?). Also, [don't post pictures of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @pault, what I am trying to achieve is that for same bene_id, rend and date, I want to create two additional fields col1 and col2. For each code the subset, it would be used as col1 code and paired with every other code in the subset as col2 code. Assuming we have `92341, v2020, v2211`, the pairs in `col1` and `col2` would be `(92341,v2020), (92341,v2211), (v2020,92341),(v2020,v2211),(v2211,92341), (v2211,v2020)`. Thanks

Comment: Self-join on those fields, and filter the results to get the pairs you want. [Here's an example of a self-join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49516848/5858851) that you should be able to work off (note it's not an answer your exact question, but the syntax will be very similar).

Comment: Thanks so @pault! This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `itertools.product` and return a Dataframe with a function, then merge on the common column:

```
f= lambda x: pd.DataFrame([(a,b) for a,b in itertools.product(x,x) if a!=b],
                    columns=['col1','col2'])
cols=['bene_id', 'rend', 'date']
m=df.groupby(cols,sort=False)['code'].apply(f).reset_index([0,1,2])
final=m.merge(df[['code','amt']],left_on='col1',right_on='code').reindex(
                               df.columns.union(['col1','col2'],sort=False),axis=1)
```

---

```
   bene_id  rend        date   code     amt   col1   col2
0      312  Pbge  06/20/2011  95951  359.93  95951  95957
1      312  Pbge  06/20/2011  95957   60.10  95957  95951
2      591   iTW  11/13/2011  92341   75.87  92341  v2020
3      591   iTW  11/13/2011  92341   75.87  92341  v2211
4      591   iTW  11/13/2011  v2020   23.77  v2020  92341
5      591   iTW  11/13/2011  v2020   23.77  v2020  v2211
6      591   iTW  11/13/2011  v2211   66.02  v2211  92341
7      591   iTW  11/13/2011  v2211   66.02  v2211  v2020
8      195   Y1b  08/25/2011  71020    9.03  71020  94060
9      195   Y1b  08/25/2011  71020    9.03  71020  94640
10     195   Y1b  08/25/2011  71020    9.03  71020  99213
11     195   Y1b  08/25/2011  94060   44.60  94060  71020
12     195   Y1b  08/25/2011  94060   44.60  94060  94640
13     195   Y1b  08/25/2011  94060   44.60  94060  99213
14     195   Y1b  08/25/2011  94640   15.53  94640  71020
15     195   Y1b  08/25/2011  94640   15.53  94640  94060
16     195   Y1b  08/25/2011  94640   15.53  94640  99213
17     195   Y1b  08/25/2011  99213   36.63  99213  71020
18     195   Y1b  08/25/2011  99213   36.63  99213  94060
19     195   Y1b  08/25/2011  99213   36.63  99213  94640
```